# How do you programmatically get the number of available slave nodes and number of executors per node at runtime in Spark/Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I want to optimize the number of partitions that I use to parallelize a collection into an RDD. Ideally I would do this with the following lines of code:

```
val numPartitions = numSlaveNodes * numExecutorsPerNode * numCoresPerExecutor
val myRDD = sparkContext.parallelize(myCollection, numPartitions)
```

I have only been able to figure out how to get the numCoresPerExecutor so far, which I do with:

```
sparkSession.conf.get("spark.executor.cores").toInt
```

Is it possible to programmatically get the other two values (numSlaveNodes and numExecutorsPerNode)? I already know how to get the number of cores per executor.